# Is there any conflict between opencv and tesseract?

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr

I use tesseract and opencv in my project.

But the problem is when I use opencv to show the image, there only appear the image window but the image didn't appear and it was totally grey.

If I comment the codes related to tesseract, the opencv can shoow image properly.

It's so weird. Can any body help me?

Thanks in advance!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main() {
// [1]
const char* imagename = "phototest.tif";
Mat img = imread(imagename);
if(img.empty())
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Can not load image %s\n", imagename);
    return -1;
}
imshow("image", img);

tesseract::TessBaseAPI *myOCR = 
        new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();

// [2]
printf("Tesseract-ocr version: %s\n",
       myOCR->Version());
printf("Leptonica version: %s\n",
       getLeptonicaVersion());

// [3]
if (myOCR->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
  exit(1);
}

// [4]
Pix *pix = pixRead("phototest.tif");
myOCR->SetImage(pix);

// [5]
char* outText = myOCR->GetUTF8Text();
printf("OCR output:\n\n");
printf(outText);

// [6]
myOCR->Clear();
myOCR->End();
delete [] outText;
pixDestroy(&pix);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you provide a small code snippet showing how you are using tesseract and how you are drawing the image? I've used tesseract together with opencv before and had no problems.

Comment: ok. I have posted my code already. It's very simple. Just want to show  the input image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to add a cv::waitkey(10) somewhere after your imshow, that may solve your problem.
You can replace system(pause) by cv::waitkey(-1) also.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. But it takes a lot of time for it to show. Is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: What is the size of your image ? Usually it's quite quick. And where did you write the cv::waitKey ? In place of your pause or just after imwrite ? Drawing of the image will be done during the cv::waitKey, keep it in mind.

Comment: I put it in place system("pause"). But if I put the cv::waitKey(-1) just after the imshow, the tesseract results can't be printed out. What's the problem?

Comment: cv::waitKey(-1) wait infinitely until you press a key... So if you set it just after imshow, the code after cv::waitKey will never be executed until you press a key. Try to set cv::waitKey(10) just after imshow, and a cv::waitKey(-1) inplace of system(pause)... What is the size of your image ?